# making connection to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm trying to move from mysql_* functions to mysqli_* functions. But I'm getting an error in trying to establish a connection to a MySQL database. In the following, the uncommented lines (using mysql_* functions) work in PHP 5.6, but the others don't. If I use mysqli_connect without the database name, $link is established, but then the mysqli_select_db fails. If I use mysqli_connect with the database name, the first routine fails.

```
        if(!($link=mysql_pconnect($hostname,$username,$password))) {
//if(!($link=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password))) {
//if(!($link=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databaseName))) {
    DisplayErrMsg(sprintf("Error connecting to host %s, by user %s",
        $hostname, $username));
    exit();
}

// Select the database
if(!mysql_select_db($databaseName,$link)){
//if(!mysqli_select_db($link, $databaseName)){
    DisplayErrMsg(sprintf("Error in selecting %s database",$databaseName));
    DisplayErrMsg(sprintf("Error: %d %s", mysql_errno($link), mysql_error($link)));
    exit();
}
```

I am able to examine my database in phpMyAdmin using the values for the variables identified above.
The error I get is "DB Error, could not list tables MySQL Error: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: The problem is not in the php code, but in the permissions on the server. Look at the user table in mysql with phpmyadmin. (fwiw, I think it's easier to understand your settings if you use mysqlworkbench to look at those settings).

Comment: In the code above, $username is "ken". In phpMyAdmin, under User Privilieges, the grantee is 'ken'@'%', table catalog in 'def', privilege type is USAGE, and IS_GRANTABLE is NO. Should I be changing $username? Where is 'www-data' coming from?

Comment: Maybe you've got more serious config errors in mysql. check the ownership of the data folder in mysql. on my system mysql data is owned by _mysql. www-data is the owner of my web directory.